# The name namehere does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have got some code which has recently broken for some reason, I can't seem to see an issue. I'm simply attempting to use some converters within my Styles.

Here is the XAML ResourceDirtionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement"
                    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement.Converters">
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Fonts/#FontAwesome</FontFamily>
    <Visibility x:Key="AdminOnly">Collapsed</Visibility>

    <!--<General:CheckBoxConverter x:Key="CheckBoxConverter" /> -->
    <Converters:StartPointConverter x:Key="StartPointConverter" />
    <Converters:ArcSizeConverter x:Key="ArcSizeConverter" />
    <Converters:ArcEndPointConverter x:Key="ArcEndPointConverter" />
    <Converters:LargeArcConverter x:Key="LargeArcConverter" />
    <Converters:SizeTextOnParent x:Key="SizeTextOnParent" />
    <Converters:Difference x:Key="Difference" />
```

Getting an error on each convert line:

> The name "StartPointConverter" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:PhotoManagement.Converters".

This is the convert, note the namespace is the same as reference above, I have attempted multiple rebuilds of the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace PhotoManagement.Converters
{
    public class StartPointConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double && ((double)value > 0.0))
            {
                return new Point((double)value / 2, 0);
            }

            return new Point();
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You provided the `ArcEndPointConverter` converter, but the error is looking for the `StartPointConverter`. Do you have that class within the namespace?

Comment: Woops, my mistake. It does this on a all of my converters anyway, but I have added the correct class.